# How to get Country, State, City, Postcode, Country code by using Google Autocomplete in IONIC App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, autocomplete

I need to get data(Country, State, City, Postcode, Country code) by using Google Autocomplete where user put there address in app.

For Google api I use:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry&sensor=false

I try lot of AngularJs and Ionic Plugin for IONIC App but not get success like as:

1. https://github.com/iazi/ngMapAutocomplete
2. https://github.com/vskosp/vsGoogleAutocomplete
3. https://github.com/ivanthecrazy/ion-place-autocomplete
4. https://github.com/israelidanny/ion-google-place

Please help me if Any one work on it or face this type of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem my using this Plugin:

https://market.ionic.io/plugins/ion-google-autocomplete